# asp.net multiple updatepanel usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

So, I have a usercontrol with an update panel. 
I also put a button for updating the panel on my control.
I include this control 2 times (or more) in a page.
I want update only one of them but when I use the button, both panel is updated.

control ascx

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function bt_click()
  {        
     __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', 'post');
     return false;
  }
  </script>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" Value="false" />
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Val"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

control .vb

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        }
    }
```

webform.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="bt" OnClientClick="bt_click" />
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    &nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Val"></asp:Label>
    <div>
        <My:MyControl ID="MyControl1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <My:MyControl ID="MyControl2" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

webform.vb

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT FOR WORKING SOLUTION:***

Here's what the error is: Your `Button1` is outside of the UpdatePanels, thus posting back your page and all the controls with it.  Hence both of them being updated.  You can't add the button in the `Triggers` section of your control, because obviously the control doesn't know about it.  So what you have to do is register that button as an Asynchronous PostBack Control.  Here's what I did:

**TestControl.ascx:**

*Note: I had to add `UpdateMode="Conditional"` to the UpdatePanel, which yours did not have. By default, UpdateMode is set to Always, and that would cause us further issues.*

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_TestControl" %>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" Value="false" />
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Val"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**TestControl.ascx.cs:**

*Note: I added UpdatePanel() as a property to get around needing to use your `__doPostBack()` calls in jQuery and I can easily access this from the parent page in the click event handler.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Controls_TestControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    public UpdatePanel UpdatePanel() { return UpdatePanel1; } 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Test.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="TestControl" Src="~/Controls/TestControl.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Fire UpdatePanel1" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Val"></asp:Label>
        <br /><br />
        <uc:TestControl ID="TestControl1" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <uc:TestControl ID="TestControl2" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Test.aspx.cs:**

*Note: Here is where I registered `Button1` in the `Page_Load` with `ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Button1);`*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Button1);

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        TestControl1.UpdatePanel().Update();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you viewed the source to see what the ID's of both UpdatePanels really are?

Comment: I know that both of them pass in the page load, so I just need to get something that will say wich one I want to update. But I try and didnt find anything that working

Comment: Hang on, I'm creating a test website with your problem and I'll fix it and get back to you.

Comment: tank you, its working, I just need to look change my code because usely its not a button who call the update but a js function because I do other things, client side, before postback.

Comment: and the action is on the control not in the page

Comment: No problem. You still do this without the `__doPostBack()` worry. Just use a hidden button that's registered asynchronously, as in the solution I provided.  In your jQuery, whenever you finish your processing, just call the `.click()` method of that button and off you go.

Comment: The "action" meaning the triggering event is on the control?

Comment: If that's the case, you could just put `<Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" /</Triggers>` inside of your UpdatePanel at the same level `<ContentTemplate />` is.

Comment: I try, I just need to give the scriptmanager to the control (he need it but not own it)

Comment: so, I did it, but, my call seems wrong. 
I use $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(); 
and he update both of them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9741/discussion-between-scott-and-forx)